# Parse log entries for the latest 30 mins

Tags: powershell

I am trying to parse  a log that has dates in the front of every line. It's a text file:

```
17.08.2020 11:26:43
17.08.2020 11:26:43 
17.08.2020 11:27:05
17.08.2020 11:29:19

get-date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

Get-Date will give me the right format, but how do I list only the entries say for the last 30 mins?

Comment: [1] use `[datetime]` to convert the items to datetime objects. [2] use `[datetime]::now` to get the current datetime. [3] subtract the 1st from the 2nd. [4] filter by that time difference to get only the ones that are less than the target age.

Comment: Any updates? ...

Answer (score 0):

If the log file can be imported as a CSV file, this is pretty straight-forward operation. The samples don't mind the date, only time part. Expanding today's date handling should be easy enough. Use `Get-Date` and `.AddMinutes(-30)` to get a date that's 30 minutes ago.

As an example, consider semicolon `;` as separator like so,

```
# Create test data
$cc = ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";" @'
date;time;content
17.08.2020;11:26:43;data 1
17.08.2020;11:26:43;data 2
17.08.2020;11:27:05;data 3
17.08.2020;11:29:19;data 4
'@

# Use where-object and casting to datetime to filter. Hard-coded time
# so the example works even if event's not within 30 minutes anymore
$cc | ? { [datetime]$_.time -ge [datetime]"11:27:00" }
# Output
date       time     content
----       ----     -------
17.08.2020 11:27:05 data 3
17.08.2020 11:29:19 data 4
```

If the log file doesn't contain suitable characters for separating date and time from actual messages, the import is going to be a bit more tricky. A quick and dirty approach uses `.Substring()` method to extract time and converts that into a datetime for comparison. Like so,

```
# Sample data, space separator might be in log message too
$data= @(
'17.08.2020 11:26:43 data 1',
'17.08.2020 11:26:43 data 2',
'17.08.2020 11:27:05 data 3',
'17.08.2020 11:29:19 data 4')

# Use brute force substring to extract time. Error hangling is missing here!
# Change substring parameters to extract the whole datetime part.
$data | ? { [datetime]$_.substring(11,8) -ge [datetime]"11:27:00" }
# Output
date       time     content
----       ----     -------
17.08.2020 11:27:05 data 3
17.08.2020 11:29:19 data 4
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get all the dates from the log file:

```
$all_dates=Get-Content .\log | Get-date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

Then get the current date:

```
$current_date=Get-Date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

Then, iterate over all dates and filter based on the time difference:

```
foreach($date in $all_dates){ $ts=New-TimeSpan -Start $date -End $current_date; if (($ts.Minutes -gt 0) -and ($ts.Minutes -lt 30)) { Write-Host $date }}
```

---

For the input you've given the output is the following (at the time of writing):

```
17.08.2020 11:26:43
17.08.2020 11:26:43
17.08.2020 11:27:05
```